# How to fix “qemu-system-riscv64: Some ROM regions are overlapping These ROM regions might have been loaded by direct user request or by default.”

Tags: linux, qemu, riscv

I would like to run a Linux root filesystem for RISC-V on qemu-system-riscv64. The requirement is in here testsuits-for-oskernel/riscv-linux-rootfs at main · oscomp/testsuits-for-oskernel · GitHub

However, After I build a root filesystem as required I encountered an error when I run

```
sudo qemu-system-riscv64 -nographic -machine virt \
  -kernel bbl -append "root=/dev/vda ro console=ttyS0" \
  -drive file=riscv64-rootfs.bin,format=raw,id=hd0 \
  -device virtio-blk-device,drive=hd0 \
  -netdev type=tap,script=scripts/ifup.sh,downscript=scripts/ifdown.sh,id=net0 \
  -device virtio-net-device,netdev=net0
```

The error is

```
qemu-system-riscv64: Some ROM regions are overlapping
These ROM regions might have been loaded by direct user request or by default.
They could be BIOS/firmware images, a guest kernel, initrd or some other file loaded into guest memory.
Check whether you intended to load all this guest code, and whether it has been built to load to the correct addresses.
The following two regions overlap (in the memory address space):
/usr/share/qemu/opensbi-riscv64-generic-fw_dynamic.bin (addresses 0x0000000080000000 - 0x0000000080012630)
build/riscv-pk/bbl ELF program header segment 1 (addresses 0x0000000080000000 - 0x000000008000690d)
make: *** [Makefile:13: run] Error 1
```

I ran this project on virtual machine of Ubuntu 22.04, is the problem possible related to run a virtual machine on a virtual machine? Or related to the version of Ubuntu? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to load your file 'bbl' at the same address where QEMU is automatically loading the opensbi firmware. Either you need to tell QEMU not to load the firmware, or you need to link your 'bbl' file to go somewhere else.